# Find the latest sequence of TRUEs with length equal or greater than n

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I've got a data like below:

```
library(dplyr)
ex <- data.frame(bool = c(rep(FALSE, 2), rep(TRUE, 3), rep(FALSE, 2), rep(TRUE, 5), 
                      FALSE, FALSE, rep(TRUE, 6), FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)) %>%
  mutate(seq = data.table::rleid(bool)) %>% 
  group_by(seq) %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(expected_output = c(4, 4, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, rep(NA,5), 4, 4, rep(NA, 6), rep(6, 3)))
```

For every `FALSE` I need to find a latest sequence of `TRUE` with length at least of `4`. But if there's no such a sequence before (like for rows `1:2` or `6:7`), we should check forward, i.e. find the first sequence of length 4 or more that appears after the observation.

The last column of `ex` contains expected output. How can I do that (at best with `tidyverse`)?

## Edit

A solution using `tidyverse` would bes still much appreciated.

Comment: If there is no sequence directly before and directly after. Where should you look first? In front or behind. Closest? What is if font and behind are same dist appart?

Comment: what does 4 and 6 refers to in your `expected_output` column?

Comment: @denis, number of sequence from `seq` column

Comment: what should be next to row `10:11` ? `4` or `5` ??? `data.frame(bool = c(rep(TRUE, 4), rep(FALSE, 2), rep(TRUE, 3), rep(FALSE, 2), rep(TRUE, 5), 
                          FALSE, FALSE, rep(TRUE, 6), FALSE, FALSE, FALSE))`

Comment: @jakes. My and Aarons solution work for the new data. Where do you have an issue? What's the error/ wrong outcome?

Comment: is your data still `group_by`? Try calling `ungroup()` before.

Comment: does `ex2$out <- fun(ex2$bool)` work?

Comment: @AndreElrico, it was, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following should work using base R.

```
function(col,min_seq =4)
{
    end = c(which(c(col[-1],NA)!=col),length(col))   
    num = diff(c(0,end))     
    start = end-num+1 
    seq_n = seq_along(start) 
    v=col[end]

    accept = num >= min_seq & v
    st = start[accept]
    sn = seq_n[accept]
    en = end[accept]
    en_ = en
    en_[1]=1
    place = rep(sn, diff(c(en_,length(col) + 1 )))      # If row with start of sequence is wanted instead of sequence number sn can be replaced with st
    place[col]=NA

    return(place)
}
```

Comment: its appears your solution does not set the last value of the seq.

Comment: @Andre Elrico, I have fixed it. Thank you for letting me know, I really should check things better.

Comment: your solution inspired me to take a function approach as well. I think your solution is very good! It also handles all of my border cases "correctly"!

Comment: your solution look neat, but I have difficulties to follow - could you please comment your steps? what's the goal of `end` or `start`?

Comment: @jakes please, run code line by line. Ask a specific question to what is unclear. Please mark a solution as answer if it solved your issue. Feel free to show some approval by upvoting an answer you like.

Comment: end, start and num are used for indexing. they are the end and start of each sequence of a new value. num is the length of each sequence. This is information that is often useful about many vectors, especially if you want to avoid loops. seq_n, is the number of the sequence (with regard to start, end or num), v is then the value held in each sequence. Accept is a logic vector to know which sequences are positive and meet the min_seq condition. st isn't used, sn is the sequences that are valid. en are the end places of valid sequences. en_ allows backward assignment of first valid sequence.

Comment: The use of the rep function assigning the value to place is pure witchcraft

Comment: Still can't see how this checks backwards and then, if not found forwards.

Comment: This relates to the line en_[1]=1. Basically, everything up to the first valid sequence belongs to the first valid sequence. As such, knowing where the first valid sequence is allows everything before it to be taken care of, it just becomes a question of assigning NA to TRUEs

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

**define function:** (robust and with error handling)

```
fun1<-
function(vec, min_rep = 4) {

    stopifnot(length(vec)>0, all(vec %in% 0:1))

    runL <- do.call(rbind,rle(vec))
    lngth<- ncol(runL)
    runL <- rbind(runL, seq = 1:lngth, seq2 = NA^runL[2,])

    runL[3,] <- ifelse(!runL[2,]|runL[1,]<min_rep, NA, runL[3,]) 

    cases <- na.omit(runL[3,])

    if(length(cases)>0) {

        for(i in rev(cases)) {
            runL[4,1:i][!is.na(runL[4,1:i])] <- i
        }

        for(i in cases) {
            runL[4,i:lngth][!is.na(runL[4,i:lngth])] <- i
        }
    } else { runL[4,] <- NA }

    return(rep(runL[4,],runL[1,]))
}
```

---

**call function:**

```
vec = c(rep(FALSE, 2), rep(TRUE, 3), rep(FALSE, 2), rep(TRUE, 5), 
        FALSE, FALSE, rep(TRUE, 6), FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
cbind(vec,fun1(vec))

vec = rep(T,5)
cbind(vec,fun1(vec))

vec = rep(F,5)
cbind(vec,fun1(vec))

vec = c(rep(F,5),T)
cbind(vec,fun1(vec))

vec = c()
cbind(vec,fun1(vec))

vec = 1:3
cbind(vec,fun1(vec))
```

Answer (score 0):

If OP strictly does not want a `data.table` solution, I can take down this post.

Here is a possible `data.table` approach:

```
#aggregate the dataset by bool and rleid
agg <- DT[, .(rn=.GRP, N=.N), by=.(bool, seq=rleid(bool))]

#extract all the TRUE sequences with length >= 4
true4s <- agg[(bool) & N >= 4L]

    #for rows that are FALSE
agg[(!bool), expOut := {
        prev <- NA

        #find the previous sequence of TRUEs by using data.table non-equi join 
        #(a rolling join will work too here)
        #in addition, do the match in reverse so that we can fill NA with prev value
        ans <- true4s[.SD[order(-rn)], {
            if (.N > 0L) {
                prev <- seq[.N] 
            } 
            prev
              #for each row in i (see ?data.table for i argument and also ?.EACHI)
                          #non equi join where earlier row in x to be join with later row in i 
        }, by=.EACHI, on=.(rn<rn)]$V1

        #for the rolling version
        #}, by=.EACHI, on=.(rn), roll=Inf]$V1

        rev(ans)
    }]

#add expected output to original dataset
DT[, expected_output := inverse.rle(list(values=agg$expOut, lengths=agg$N))]
```

output:

```
     bool expected_output
 1: FALSE               4
 2: FALSE               4
 3:  TRUE              NA
 4:  TRUE              NA
 5:  TRUE              NA
 6: FALSE               4
 7: FALSE               4
 8:  TRUE              NA
 9:  TRUE              NA
10:  TRUE              NA
11:  TRUE              NA
12:  TRUE              NA
13: FALSE               4
14: FALSE               4
15:  TRUE              NA
16:  TRUE              NA
17:  TRUE              NA
18:  TRUE              NA
19:  TRUE              NA
20:  TRUE              NA
21: FALSE               6
22: FALSE               6
23: FALSE               6
     bool expected_output
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(bool = c(rep(FALSE, 2), rep(TRUE, 3), rep(FALSE, 2), rep(TRUE, 5), 
    FALSE, FALSE, rep(TRUE, 6), FALSE, FALSE, FALSE))
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! It's not like I don't want to `data.table` solution, I just don't know anything 'bout `data.table` syntax and I need a solution I'd be able to understand. But I think it should stay for anybody who'll come hear from searching.